# Issue with Enterprise build and UUID usage

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keychain, udid

As you know Apple recently deprecated the usage of UDID. So my solution to this was

1. Generate CFUUID
2. Save it to keychain
3. Re-access the keychain item there after.

This has been working good. But, for some reason we recently saw that with the installation of an enterprise build we are getting a different UUID(Which was supposed to be stored on keychain with our unique access key).

Did any one come across such situation? Here is the code to create the UUID and store it onto keychain..

```
+ (NSString *)registerUUIDWithKeyChain
{
CFUUIDRef udid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *uuidString = (NSString *) CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, udid);

KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"UniqueApp" accessGroup:nil];

NSString *userName = @"UniqueAppName";
NSString *password = uuidString;

[keychainItem setObject:userName forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychainItem setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];

[keychainItem release]; 

return uuidString;

}

+ (NSString *)userUUID
{
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"UniqueApp" accessGroup:nil];

//Accesing the v_data was the only way. For some reason there is a runtime issue if we try to access it though "kSecValueData"
NSString *uuid = [keychainItem.keychainItemData objectForKey:@"v_Data"];

//Check if the app is installed for the first time on the device. If YES register the UUID in to the keychain.
//Also check if it is a reinstall by accessing the previous keyChainItem with our Identifier.
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstRun"] intValue] == 0 && !(uuid.length > 0)) 
{
    uuid = [UIDevice_Additions registerUUIDWithKeyChain];

    NSLog(@"\n First Time Registered UUID is %@", uuid);

    //after stuff done
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"firstRun"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [keychainItem release]; 
    return uuid;
}

[keychainItem release]; 
return uuid;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Okie,

After battling with the issue for a day, I found what was triggering this.

- Keychain's are certificate dependent
- An enterprise build is created with a different certificate
- Hence, when the code tries to access your key from an enterprise build you will not find it and hence the code generates will generate a new one.
- Solution would be to create your Keychain so that it is globally accessible. You can change the accessGroup variable in the KeyChainWrapper init method.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -3):

you may use MAC Addres instread of UUID

```
- (NSString *) macaddress
{
    int                 mib[6];
    size_t              len;
    char                *buf;
    unsigned char       *ptr;
    struct if_msghdr    *ifm;
    struct sockaddr_dl  *sdl;

    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = AF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_LINK;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;

    if ((mib[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) {
        printf("Error: if_nametoindex error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 1\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((buf = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory. error!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 2");
        return NULL;
    }

    ifm = (struct if_msghdr *)buf;
    sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(ifm + 1);
    ptr = (unsigned char *)LLADDR(sdl);
    NSString *outstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", 
                           *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5)];
    free(buf);

    return outstring;
}
```

Comment: Unlike CFUUID, which generates a random key every time it's called, MAC addresses have the same social/ethical issues as UUIDs. It is unsafe to rely on the mac address being available when it seems as though MAC addresses will also be axed in the same fashion as UUIDs.

Comment: it's a Enterprise Build ,and he want to keep the UID same everytime, the MAC address won't change like UUID we used before (Apple don't allow to use it)

Comment: ok, as a Enterprise Build, you can just use UUID  ,  **[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]**

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of build it is. UUID is **deprecated**. This means it's going to be **removed** from Apple's frameworks. MAC address lookup will most likely follow. His solution is logically sound for his application. He persists a unique device token across restores by storing it in the keychain.